# PushNotification is undefined (ng-cordova)

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

In my ionic application when running the application in browser i get following error

```
ng-cordova.js:6378 Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined
```

in my console, as well as when i build the application for android and run in my phone it doesnot work there as well i.e there is no popup
for registration Id : `alert(data.registrationId);`.

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaPushV5) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      // For Push Notification

     var options = {
        android: {
          senderID: "121XXXXXXX49"
        },
        ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: "true",
          sound: "true"
        }
      };

      // initialize
      $cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function() {
        // start listening for new notifications
        $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
        // start listening for errors
        $cordovaPushV5.onError();

        // register to get registrationId
        $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function(data) {
          // `data.registrationId` save it somewhere;
          alert(data.registrationId);
        })
      });

      // triggered every time notification received
      $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data){
        alert(data.title + ' - '+ data.message);
        // data.message,
        // data.title,
        // data.count,
        // data.sound,
        // data.image,
        // data.additionalData
      });

      // triggered every time error occurs
      $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOcurred', function(event, e){
        alert(e.message);
        // e.message
      });  

  });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at ngCordova page it is said "Cordova plugins do not work while developing in your browser". This is the reason why it is not working in the browser.

See the link here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Before initializing the plugin you should check if app is running on device (not in browser) and ionic platform is ready. Then if you follow the link properly you are good to go.

The link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

My personal advice is you don't have to use ng-cordova since new phonegap-push plugin is out there. You don't need to use any other things. You can basically do the following without using ng-cordova.

**Make sure you check if ionic platform is ready and the platform is not browser.**

```
var pushConfig = {
    android: {
        senderID: "blabla"
    },
    ios: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    }
};

var push = window.PushNotification.init(pushConfig);

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    var token = data.registrationId
    console.log('OK: register notfy ', token);
});
```

Detailed information is here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: i have done exactly the same, that you said, but when i run the app in andriod phone i didn't get the redistrationId.

Comment: What error you get? Can you give more details? @gudboisgn

Comment: i have assigned the **data.registrationId** in my **$rootScope.regId**  and when i print it to the view with {{ regId }} . its just empty. @orhankutlu

Comment: Can you first try to console.log(data.registrationId) as i show on my answer?

Comment: in browser i get: PushNotification is not defined , and  android phone how to see console.log() data? @orhankutlu

Comment: Make 'adb logcat" to your application. You can do something like ``adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep your.package.name | cut -c10-15``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117402/discussion-between-orhankutlu-and-gudboisgn).

Comment: not such a good idea to fix this issue via chat. I needed an answer to the same question too